# Boolean value cant convert to string

Tags: java, string, boolean, output

I am writing a program calculating speeding ticket cost based on speedlimit, mph but most importantly if they were in a school zone and I am having trouble in public(ticket) as my boolean

```java
   if (schoolZone.equals("Y")) {
          schoolZone = true;
       } else {
          schoolZone = false;
       }
   }
```

wont work. It seems it cant convert it to the string value and I am looking for help in this as I am pretty new to computer science

```java
      public class Ticket {
    
       /*
       * Instance variable for ticket
       */
       private String name, TDL, address, city, state, zip;
    
       private int postedSpeed, travelling, ticketAmount, day, month, year;
    
       private boolean schoolZone;
    
       // default constructor
       public Ticket() {
    
       }
    
       // parameterized constructor
       public Ticket(String name, String tDL, String address, String city, String state, String zip, int postedSpeed,
               int travelling, int ticketAmount, int day, int month, int year, String schoolZone) {
           name = name;
           TDL = tDL;
           address = address;
           city = city;
           state = state;
           zip = zip;
           postedSpeed = postedSpeed;
           travelling = travelling;
           ticketAmount = ticketAmount;
           day = day;
           month = month;
           year = year;
           if (schoolZone.equals("Y")) {    
               schoolZone = true;
           } else {
               schoolZone = false;
           }
       }
    
       // calculate ticket
       public void calTicket() {
    
           double fine = 0.0;
           if (travelling > (postedSpeed + 30) && schoolZone == true) {
    
               fine = 2 * (6 * (travelling - postedSpeed) + 160 + ticketAmount);
           } else if (travelling > postedSpeed && schoolZone == true) {
    
               fine = 2 * (6 * (travelling - postedSpeed) + ticketAmount);
           } else if (travelling > (postedSpeed + 30)) {
    
               fine = ticketAmount + 160 + 6 * (travelling - postedSpeed);
           } else if (travelling > postedSpeed) {
    
               fine = ticketAmount + 6 * (travelling - postedSpeed);
           } else if (travelling < postedSpeed) {
    
               fine = 0;
           }
           if (schoolZone == true) {
               System.out.println("Dear Citizen Knight,\n" + "You have received this citation for driving " + travelling
                       + " mph in an area with a posted speed limit of " + postedSpeed + ".\r\n" + "\r\n"
                       + "This violation occurred in a school zone.\r\n" + "\r\n" + "Your fine is $" + fine
                       + " and can be paid at the address below.\r\n" + "\r\n"
                       + "Please remember to buckle up and drive safely.");
           } else {
    
               System.out.println("Dear Citizen Knight,\n" + "You have received this citation for driving " + travelling
                       + " mph in an area with a posted speed limit of " + postedSpeed + ".\r\n" + "\r\n"
                       + "This violation didn't occurred in a school zone.\r\n" + "\r\n" + "Your fine is $" + fine
                       + " and can be paid at the address below.\r\n" + "\r\n"
                       + "Please remember to buckle up and drive safely.");
           }
       }
    
       // return last name
       public String lastName() {
    
           String[] names = name.split("\\s+");
           return names[names.length - 1];
       }
    
       // toString method to get details
       public String toString() {
    
           return month + "/" + day + "/" + year + "\n" + name + "(TDL: " + TDL + ")\n" + address + "\n" + city + ", "
                   + state + ", " + zip + "\n";
       }
    }
    
    
    
    //Runner
    import java.util.Scanner;
    
    public class TicketRunner {
    
       public static void main(String[] args) {
    
           //Scanner object
           Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    
           //printing programmer details
           System.out.println("The Speeding Ticket Program");
           System.out.println();
           System.out.println("By: John Smith");
    
           System.out.println("\n===================================\n");
    
           //input driver data
           System.out.print("Name of Driver? --> ");
           String name = keyboard.nextLine();
            
             System.out.print("TDL? -->");
           String tdl = keyboard.nextLine();
           
           System.out.print("Address? -->");
           String address = keyboard.nextLine();
          
           System.out.print("City? -->");
           String city = keyboard.nextLine();
           
           System.out.print("State? -->");
           String state = keyboard.nextLine();
          
           System.out.print("Zip? -->");
           String zip = keyboard.nextLine();
          
           System.out.print("Did the violation occur in a school zone? {Y/N} -->");
           String zone = keyboard.nextLine();
    
           System.out.println("Date of Violation:");
    
           System.out.print("Month (number)? --> ");
           int month = keyboard.nextInt();
           System.out.print("Day? -->");
           int day = keyboard.nextInt();
           System.out.print("Year? -->");
           int year = keyboard.nextInt();
           System.out.print("What is the posted speed limit? -->");
           int postedSpeed = keyboard.nextInt();
           System.out.print("How fast was the car travelling in mph? --> ");
           int travelling = keyboard.nextInt();
    
           //instantiate ticket
           Ticket ticket = new Ticket(name, tdl, address, city, state, zip, postedSpeed, travelling, 75, day, month, year,
                   zone);
    
           //print ticket details
           System.out.println(ticket.toString());
           ticket.calTicket();
           keyboard.close();//close scanner
       }
    }
    /********************output******************/
```

Answer (score 3):

You should have included `this` keyword when setting fields on your constructor. To fix your issue use the code below:

```
if (schoolZone.equals("Y")) {
    this.schoolZone = true;
} else {
    this.schoolZone = false;
}
```

Note that `schoolZone` from your parameter is in **String** and the `schoolZone` in your class is in **boolean**. What happened in your constructor was the parameter `schoolZone` in String type was the one being set with a boolean value which obviously would not work.

Comment: And still better: `this.schoolZone = schoolZone.equals("Y");`

Answer (score 1):

Your basic problem is called NAME SHADOWING.
In java you basically can have three different types of variables:

1. member variables (static or not)
2. parameter variables
3. method variables (inside methods)
   Because they all relate to the same substance, it is quite commonplace that they also happen to have the same exact name. thus you get name collisions and shadowing.

My personal solution to prevent that is:

- using strict warnings for the compiler
- prefixing my variables, as seen below

My class layouts and variable prefixes

- static final 'variables' e.g. constants
- static structures like static inner classes, interfaces etc
- static variables, prefixed with 's'
- static methods
- non-static inner classes etc
- final member variables for graphics/UI, prefixed with g or c, for general graphics and controls
- non-final member variables for graphics/UI, prefixed with g or c, for general graphics and controls
- final member variables for logic (i.e. the normal member variables), prefixed with m
- non-final member variables for logic (i.e. the normal member variables), prefixed with m
- constructors
- initializer methods
- overriding methods like toString(), hashCode(), equals() etc
- simple getters and setters (C#: property methods)
- hardcore logic methods

Additionally, I prefix method parameters with

- p for parameter (= @NonNull, @NotNull)
- o for optional (@Nullable)
- r for return/out values (C#, or state objects to write to, like accumulator lists etc)

NOTE: I make the biggest difference in my code about static / non-static.
Usually I separate that code into two files/classes, unless it's only 1 variable and 1 method, or absolutely necessary to have static code in an object-focused class.
For beginners, the static trap is usually the source of most evil problems.

The prefixing I do has served me really really well.
I have very strict warning rules in my IDE, one of them is NAME SHADOWING.
I also have set up Eclipse to automatically generate prefixed.

But other people might find this style hindering or just plain ugly.
Learn what your teams use, adapt. If you code on your own, think about it a bit, try it a bit, maybe you find something that's to your liking.

Here's a rework of your code in my style, along with some hints:

```
package stackoverflow;

import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.Objects;

public class Ticket {

    static public String toLastName(final String pFullName) {
        if (pFullName == null) return null; // fail fast, fail early: we could also throw an exception here

        final String[] names = pFullName.split("\\s+");
        return names[names.length - 1];
    }




    /*
    * Instance variable for ticket
    */
    // if member variables are truly immutable, and you can have them final, then you can make em public final, so you dont need getters
    // BUT: if you're planning on using advanced Java features, with bytecode manipulation, reflection, like Java EE or aspect-oriented libraries,
    // you better stick to the getter/setters at all times
    public final String     mTDL;
    public final String     mAddress;
    public final String     mCity;
    public final String     mState;
    public final String     mZipCode;
    public final int        mPostedSpeedMph;
    public final int        mTravellingSpeedMph;
    public final int        mTicketAmount;
    public final int        mDay;
    public final int        mMonth;
    public final int        mYear;
    public final boolean    mSchoolZone;

    private String mName; // name can be changed du to marriage

    // default constructor
    // public Ticket() {} // this will not create a valid state, so we leave it out unless it's essential
    // if it's truly essential to your code, use a flag and a getter to see if you're interacting with valid objects

    // parameterized constructor
    public Ticket(final String pName, final String pTDL, final String pAddress, final String pCity, final String pState, final String pZipCode,
            final int pPostedSpeedMph, final int pTravellingSpeedMph, final int pTicketAmount,
            final int pDay, final int pMonth, final int pYear, final String pSchoolZone) {
        mName = pName;
        mTDL = pTDL;
        mAddress = pAddress;
        mCity = pCity;
        mState = pState;
        mZipCode = pZipCode;
        mPostedSpeedMph = pPostedSpeedMph; // it's better to explicitly name the unit. keeps you and others out of trouble
        mTravellingSpeedMph = pTravellingSpeedMph; // especially interesting in time units: is this parameter in seconds or milliseconds?
        mTicketAmount = pTicketAmount;
        mDay = pDay;
        mMonth = pMonth;
        mYear = pYear;
        mSchoolZone = "Y".equals(pSchoolZone); // use one-line assignments and conditionals when possible
        // also when trying to match two strings, beware of the NullPointerException. Having constants as first operand dodges that problem
    }



    public String getName() { // simple getter, for the only non-final member variable
        return mName;
    }



    // calculate ticket
    public void calcTicket() {
        final double fine = calcFine();
        final DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##"); // kicking a raw float to the string might get ugly results at times.
        // use dedicated formatting to prevent that

        final String schoolZoneText = mSchoolZone ? "This violation occurred in a school zone." : "This violation did not occurr in a school zone.";
        final String output = "Dear Citizen Knight " + getName() + ",\n\n"
                + "You have received this citation for driving " + mTravellingSpeedMph
                + " mph in an area with a posted speed limit of " + mPostedSpeedMph + ".\r\n"
                + "\r\n"
                + schoolZoneText + "\r\n"
                + "\r\n" + "Your fine is $" + df.format(fine) + " and can be paid at the address below.\r\n"
                + "\r\n"
                + "Please remember to buckle up and drive safely.";
        /* HINT: do NOT mix \n and \r\n and \n\r and \r newlines! Stick to one. Java tries to works with \n alone.
         * Unless it's too much of a hassle, try to convert to \n, then work with \n internally and only re-convert at output,
         * if you need specific newline control.
         * Also, its is easier if you have the text somewhat outlined like the output is supposed to be displayed
         */

        System.out.println(output);

        // I left a remnant of your old code to tell you sth else:
        //if (mSchoolZone) { // if(true==true) is a bit overkill, if(true) usually suffices
    }

    public int calcFine() { // have this as its own method, to it is more focused and can be used from other places too, f conventient
        // early return approach: jump back as soon as solution is done. this way it is easier for the compiler to see problems and warn you.
        // here are also lots of magic numbers, that in other cases should be replaced by constants
        if (mTravellingSpeedMph > (mPostedSpeedMph + 30) && mSchoolZone == true) return 2 * (6 * (mTravellingSpeedMph - mPostedSpeedMph) + 160 + mTicketAmount);
        else if (mTravellingSpeedMph > mPostedSpeedMph && mSchoolZone == true) return 2 * (6 * (mTravellingSpeedMph - mPostedSpeedMph) + mTicketAmount);
        else if (mTravellingSpeedMph > (mPostedSpeedMph + 30)) return mTicketAmount + 160 + 6 * (mTravellingSpeedMph - mPostedSpeedMph);
        else if (mTravellingSpeedMph > mPostedSpeedMph) return mTicketAmount + 6 * (mTravellingSpeedMph - mPostedSpeedMph);
        // else if (mTravelling < mPostedSpeed) return 0; we actually do not even need this line
        return 0; // my compiler told me we need this, so then I realized the line above was redundant
    }

    // return last name
    public String getLastName() { // we call them GETTERS and SETTERS
        return toLastName(mName);
    }

    // toString method to get details
    @Override public String toString() { // do not forget annotations like @Override etc, they may hint at possible problems
        return mMonth + "/" + mDay + "/" + mYear + "\n" + mName + "(TDL: " + mTDL + ")\n" + mAddress + "\n" + mCity + ", "
                + mState + ", " + mZipCode + "\n";
    }

    /*
     * Here a fine little method that shows where my prefixing really helps.
     * Of course, I bent the naming to showcase this.
     */
    public String takeLastName(final String pName) { // in case of marriage
        final String name = toLastName(pName);
        final String[] myNameParts = mName.split("\\s+");
        myNameParts[myNameParts.length - 1] = name;
        mName = String.join(" ", myNameParts);
        return mName;
    }
    public boolean hasSameLastNameAs(final String pOtherName) {
        final String otherLastName = toLastName(pOtherName);
        final String myLastName = toLastName(mName);
        return Objects.equals(otherLastName, myLastName);
    }



    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final Ticket t = new Ticket("Peter Lustig", null, null, null, null, null, 30, 60, 2, 14, 1, 2021, "Y");
        t.calcTicket();
        t.takeLastName("Hans Dampf");
        System.out.println("\n\n\nAfter his marriage, he is now called " + t.getName());

    }

}
```

Comment: I do like your style

Answer (score 0):

Totally agree with Donato, must use "this" in constructor on the left side to access the class variables and set those properly else the passed argument will set it to itself.

Answer (score 0):

When referring to the instance variables via the constructor, (sometimes via the methods also) you should use `this` keyword. It implies to the compiler that you are referring to the instance variable rather than the local variables.

In your case, local variable `schoolZone` is in type of `String` and the instance variable `schoolZone` is a `boolean`. So your code has to be like following.

```
if (schoolZone.equalsIgnoreCase("Y")) {
    this.schoolZone = true;          
} else {       
    this.schoolZone = false;
}
```

P.S. : My opinion is to use `equalsIgnoreCase()` instead of `equals()` because there is a possibility for the user to input "Y" or "N" in lowercase also.

Accordingly, your entire `constructor` has to be edited in the following manner.

```
// parameterized constructor
   public Ticket(String name, String tDL, String address, String city, String state, 
                 String zip, int postedSpeed, int travelling, int ticketAmount, int day, 
                 int month, int year, String schoolZone) {
       this.name = name;
       this.TDL = tDL;
       this.address = address;
       this.city = city;
       this.state = state;
       this.zip = zip;
       this.postedSpeed = postedSpeed;
       this.travelling = travelling;
       this.ticketAmount = ticketAmount;
       this.day = day;
       this.month = month;
       this.year = year;

       if (schoolZone.equalsIgnoreCase("Y")) {
          this.schoolZone = true;
       } else {
           this.schoolZone = false;
       }
   }
```